# Creating xts file in R from Data frame

Tags: r, xts

```
      DATE  TIME OPEN  HIGH  LOW   CLOSE VOLUME
01/02/1998 09:31 37.81 37.86 37.81 37.81  29810

01/02/1998 09:32 37.84 37.86 37.81 37.86  36711
```

I am working with the above data set IBM. I am trying to convert this data frame into an xts file. I would like the DATE and TIME to be in the same column as a single time stamp.  Have tried joining them with cbind or paste and then converting them from chr to date class using as.date, then as.POSIXlt  before the xts conversion using as.xts.  Continuously getting an error. Any ideas would be appreciated.

This is the code I have used,

```
IBM$DATE<- paste(IBM$DATE,IBM$TIME,sep=" ") #to join DATE and TIME
IBM$TIME <- NULL # to remove TIME column
IBM$DATE<-as.Date(IBM$DATE, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") #convert DATE from chr to date
IBM$DATE<- as.POSIXct(IBM$DATE)
IBM<-as.xts(IBM)
```

I get the following error.

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Try `xts(df1[-(1:2)], order.by = as.POSIXct(paste(df1$DATE, df1$TIME), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))`

Comment: Please consider adding to your question the code you tried out (as you claim) along with its output (if any). This would help us answer within the desired context.

Comment: Thank you akrun - works perfectly